# Add rows to class bound datagridview

Tags: vb.net, class, datagridview

Hi I'm trying to bind a list of objects to a datagridview 
Binding a existing list(Of is working but I'm trying to add or remove a object from, my dgv isn't updating.

```
    Public Class Form1
    Dim lt As New List(Of Test)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lt.Add(New Test("Mac", 2200))
        lt.Add(New Test("PC", 1100))
        dgv.DataSource = lt

        lt.Add(New Test("Android", 3300)) 'This line won't appear in the dgv
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Test
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal cost As String)
        _name = name
        _cost = cost
    End Sub
    Private _name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _cost As String
    Public Property Cost() As String
        Get
            Return _cost
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _cost = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

How can I add or remove or change a value from the dgv to the list and inverse?

NoiseBe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Dim lt As New List(Of Test)
```

To:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
...
Private lt As New BindingList(Of Test)
```

When the collection contents will change, you should use a `BindingList(Of T)`. This collection has events associated with it which make it aware of changes to the list contents.

If in addition to the list *contents*, the list *items* will change (like Test.Name), you should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class itself.

---

Another way to do it:

```
dgv.DataSource = Nothing
lt.Add(New Test("Android", 3300))
dgv.DataSource = lt
```

This "resets" the `DataSource` so that the new contents will show up.  However, it means that several other things get reset like selected items; if you are binding to a List/Combo control, you will also have to reset the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties as well.